# lifetime of a variable inside a self invoking anonymous function - function closures

Tags: javascript, function

I'm studying function closures from http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_function_closures.asp

I don't understand the below code. variable add refers to a self-invoking anonymous function which returns an anonymous function. In this case, what happens to variable counter? when we call function add, what happens?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<p>Counting with a local variable.</p>

<button type="button" onclick="myFunction()">Count!</button>

<p id="demo">0</p>

<script>
var add = (function () {
    var counter = 0;    })();
    return function () {return counter += 1;}


function myFunction(){
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = add();
}
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

in addition I dont understand why the code below does not work?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<p>Counting with a local variable.</p>

<button type="button" onclick="myFunction()">Count!</button>

<p id="demo">0</p>

<script>
var add = (function () {
    var counter = 0;
    return function () 
           {
             var semih=0;
             if(counter >5) 
             {
                 return function(){ semih += 5;  }
             }
             return counter += 1;}
           }
)();

function myFunction(){
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = add();
}
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

In the first example, counter is a global variable since the counter in the closure falls out of scope. In the second, semih should not be inside a function because innerHTML takes a string.